# Showing Links to Answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, hyperlinks

Is there a trick to showing links to answers? I notice that they all have a distinct `id`, so it’s 90% in place already. Sometimes it would be helpful link to an answer rather than a question.

I have a little JavaScript which will do this from the console:

```
var answers=document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="answer-"]');
answers.forEach(answer=>{
    var a=document.createElement('a');
    a.href=`#${answer.getAttribute('id')}`;
    a.innerHTML='';
    answer.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin',a);
});
```

and it’s not hard to turn that into a bookmarklet or an addon, but it seems that it should be an existing feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just use the share link from the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345897/135565) itself

[image: gif screenshot of the process of getting the share link of an answer]

Comment: The final `/1234567` is your own user ID which allows Stack to keep track of how many times a URL was shared via a link you posted somewhere. This can occasionally be useful, but I often trim it off. (You get a friendly but somewhat obscure badge when enough people click on the same link. It doesn't show where you shared the link, only where the link took people.)